# SQL Expression Assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am pulling data from using Telerik Standalone Reporting Application. I have a Table called "Product" one of the columns is called "`ProductStatus`". `ProductStatus` is an int value ranging from 1-12. Breakdown below:

```
"1"=Active
"2"=Retired
"3"=Processing
"5"=Archived
"6"=Active-Empty
"7"=Available
"8"=Resigned
"9"=Terminated
"10"=Legal Freeze
"11"=Admin Hold
"12"=Reserved
```

My question is: How can I write an Expression that will Look at "`ProductStatus`" and If = to 1 Then Return "`Active`" Or If = to 2 Then Return "`Retired`" etc.

Comment: Search Books on Line (the SQL Server documentation) for `CASE`.

Comment: Is there another table for product statuses which maps each numeric status to its string representation? Relational databases are usually architected that way, allowing you to `JOIN` tables.

Comment: Mr. Berkowski - No, There is no other table that defines what the number values =. I know what the number values mean, but need to display in a more user friendly way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 ways to do that

- use `CASE` and code the *translation table* in the request

  ```
  SELECT CASE WHEN 1 THEN 'Active' ... END FROM ...;
  ```
- put the translation table in a database table and use a join :

  ```
  CREATE TABLE product_status(id INTEGER, status VARCHAR(32));
  INSERT INTO product_status(id, status) VALUES(1, 'Active');
  ...
  SELECT ps.status, ... FROM product_status, ... WHERE product_status.id = ..., ... ;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with all status texts like this:

```
CREATE TABLE statusText
    ([id] int, [text] varchar(12))
;

INSERT INTO statusText
    ([id], [text])
VALUES
    (1, 'Active'),
    (2, 'Retired'),
    (3, 'Processing'),
    (5, 'Archived'),
    (6, 'Active-Empty'),
    (7, 'Available'),
    (8, 'Resigned'),
    (9, 'Terminated'),
    (10, 'Legal Freeze'),
    (11, 'Admin Hold'),
    (12, 'Reserved')
;
```

And then join Products table like this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.Text
FROM Products a INNER JOIN statusText b 
  ON a.ProductStatus=b.id
```